# when client write the message to the server, but server cannot read the message from the client in sokcet in c/c++ on linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, pthreads

My OS is linux. I program socket in C. I tested the client and the server at the same time. Both of them are on my localhost. However, when the client write the message to the server, but the server cannot read the message from the client. I have no idea that what wrong it is. I'm sure that the client and the server connect to each other. My main purpose is that the client write the message, whose content is the sequence number, to the server, and then the server can reply the message to the client back.

I use pthread to make the client can connect to the multiple servers.
the part function code from the client.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<netdb.h> //hostent
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define NAMEMAX 4096
int socket_desc;
int packet_num;
struct timeval timeout;
typedef struct server_object{
    char server_ip[100];
    uint16_t server_port;
    struct sockaddr_in server_about;
}server_object; 

void* request(void* server_func){
    server_object* server_pointer = (server_object*) server_func;
    struct timeval start;
    struct timeval end;
    struct timeval thistimeout;
    int num = 0;
    //Connect to remote server
        int test_con = connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&(server_pointer->server_about) , sizeof(server_pointer->server_about));
    printf("test_con = %d\n", test_con);    
    fd_set read_fd2;
    FD_ZERO(&read_fd2);
    FD_SET(socket_desc, &read_fd2);
    int fdmax2;
    fdmax2 = socket_desc;
    /*int ret2 = select(fdmax2+1, &read_fd2, NULL, NULL, &thistimeout);
    if(ret2 == 0){
        printf("00\n");
        printf("timeout when connect to %s:%u, seq = %d\n", server_pointer->server_ip, server_pointer->server_port, num);
        fflush(stdout);
        return 0;
    }*/
        //puts("Connected\n");
        //Send some data
    //while-loop begin
    int overtime = 0;
    while((num < packet_num && packet_num != 0) || (packet_num == 0)){
        char msg[200];
        memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
        //strcpy(msg, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
        sprintf(msg, "%d", num);
        unsigned  long diff;
            gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
        printf("msg = %s\n", msg);
        ssize_t write_s;
        write_s = write(socket_desc, msg, sizeof(msg));
        printf("write_s = %ld\n", write_s);
        printf("msg = %s\n", msg);
            //puts("write failed");
        assert(num <= INT_MAX);
        //puts("Data Send\n");
        fd_set read_fd;
        FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
        FD_SET(socket_desc, &read_fd);
        int fdmax;
        fdmax = socket_desc;
        //int ret = select(fdmax+1, &read_fd, NULL, NULL, &thistimeout);    
        //if(ret == 0){
        //  overtime = 1;
        //  break;
        //}
        //Receive a reply from the server
        char buf[2000];
        printf("readbef\n");
        read(socket_desc, buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("readafter\n");
        printf("buf = %s\n", buf);
        gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
        diff = 1000000 * (end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)+ end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec;
        thistimeout.tv_usec -= diff;
        //printf("thedifference is %ldmsec\n",diff);
        //printf("buf = %s\n", buf);
            //puts("Reply received\n");
        printf("recv from %s:%u, seq = %d, RTT = %lu msec\n", server_pointer->server_ip, server_pointer->server_port, num, diff);
        fflush(stdout);
        num++;
    }
    if(overtime == 1){
        printf("timeout when connect to %s:%u, seq = %d\n", server_pointer->server_ip, server_pointer->server_port, num);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[]){
        sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &packet_num);
    //printf("packet_num = %d\n", packet_num);
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    sscanf(argv[2], "%lu", &timeout.tv_usec);
    //printf("timeout.tv_sec = %lu, timeout.tv_usec = %lu\n", timeout.tv_sec, timeout.tv_usec);
        //Create socket
        socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    printf("socket_desc = %d\n", socket_desc);
    int j = 3;
    int t;
    int isip = 1;
    while(j < argc){
        //int new_socket
        //struct sockaddr_in server;
        server_object server;
        char hostname[NAMEMAX] = {0};
        uint16_t portnum = 0;
        int meet = 0;
        int k;
        for(k = 0; k < strlen(argv[j]); k++){
            if(argv[j][k] == ':'){
                //portnum = argv[j]+(k+1);
                meet = 1;
                t = (k+1);
                continue;
            }
            if(meet == 0){
                hostname[k] = argv[j][k];
                if(isdigit(argv[j][k]) || argv[j][k] == '.'){
                    isip = 1;
                }
                else{
                    isip = 0;
                }
            }
            if(meet == 1){
                portnum = portnum*10 + (argv[j][k] - '0');
            }
        }
            char ip[100];
        memset(ip, 0, sizeof(ip));
            struct hostent *he;
            struct in_addr **addr_list;
            int i;
        struct in_addr hipaddr;
            if(isip){
            inet_aton(hostname, &hipaddr);
            he = gethostbyaddr(&hipaddr, 4, AF_INET);
        }
        else{
                he = gethostbyname( hostname );
        }
        //Cast the h_addr_list to in_addr , since h_addr_list also has the ip address in long format only
        addr_list = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list;
            for(i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++){
                //Return the first one;
                strcpy(ip , inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]) );
            }

            //printf("%s resolved to : %s\n" , hostname , ip);
        strcpy(server.server_ip, ip);
        //printf("port = %u\n", portnum);
        server.server_port = portnum;
            server.server_about.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);    
            server.server_about.sin_family = AF_INET;
            server.server_about.sin_port = htons(portnum);
        //thread start
        pthread_t ntid;
        pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, request, &server);
        sleep(10);
        j++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I use pthread to make the server can accept the multiple clients.
the part function code from the server.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    //strlen
#include <stdlib.h>    //strlen
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <unistd.h>    //write
#include <pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
int sv_socket_desc;
typedef struct client_object{
    struct sockaddr_in client_about;
    int client_fsd;
}client_object;

void *connection_handler(void *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[]){
    int new_socket , c;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;     
    //Create socket
    sv_socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0); 
    printf("sv_socket_desc = %d\n", sv_socket_desc);
    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    //uint16_t portnum;
    //sscanf(argv[1], "%hu", &portnum);
    //server.sin_port = htons(portnum);
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 ); 
    //Bind
    bind(sv_socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));
    //Listen
    listen(sv_socket_desc , 3);     
    //Accept and incoming connection
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while( (new_socket = accept(sv_socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) ){
        //puts("Connection accepted");         
        //Reply to the client
        client_object* new_sock;
        client_object newclient;
        newclient.client_about = client;
        newclient.client_fsd = new_socket;
        //start thread
        fflush(stdout);
        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = (client_object*)malloc(sizeof(client_object));
        *new_sock = newclient;
        fflush(stdout);
        pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock);
        sleep(10);
        //thread over
        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
        //puts("Handler assigned");
    }     
    return 0;
}

/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc){
    //Get the socket descriptor
    client_object newclient = *(client_object*) socket_desc;
    ssize_t read_size;
    char client_message[200];
    memset(client_message, 0, sizeof(client_message));
    unsigned short int client_port_num = ntohs(newclient.client_about.sin_port);
    char client_addr[2000];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(newclient.client_about.sin_addr.s_addr), client_addr, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    /*fflush(stdout);
    read_size = read(sv_socket_desc, client_message, sizeof(client_message));
    printf("client_msg = %s\n", client_message);
    printf("read_size = %ld\n", read_size);
    fflush(stdout);*/
    while(1){
        //(read_size = read(sv_socket_desc, client_message, sizeof(client_message))) >= 0
        //printf("readbef\n");
        read_size = read(sv_socket_desc, client_message, sizeof(client_message));
        printf("read_size = %ld\n", read_size);     
        printf("client_message = %s\n", client_message);
        fflush(stdout);
        read_size = write(sv_socket_desc, client_message, sizeof(client_message));
        int n;
        sscanf(client_message, "%d", &n);
        printf("recv from %s:%hu, seq = %d\n", client_addr, client_port_num, n);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    //Free the socket pointer
    free(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't even check the return value of `connect` so how do you know it even succeeded? Also, note that there is no such language as C/C++. C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: The two terminal show messages about "connect" successfully.

Comment: So I really identify the problem not come from "connect" . The problem should come from somewhere.

Comment: how is sv_socket_desc initilized and where?

Comment: sv_socket_desc is in the server.c's main( ).

Comment: Should I post the entire client.c and server.c ?

Comment: In the other word, when client write the message to server, but the return value of read( ) of server is negative.

Comment: No need to add a mention hat your issue is solved, the green checkmark on the answer is enough.

Comment: A thread per connection...? I hope this is homework and this isn't part of a real world program... You'll have scaling issues and shutdown synchronization issues with this model... you already do. For homework this is great, but for real world.. brrr..

Comment: nnnn...it's just a homework. I'm just a newbie with respect to network-programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eddie Lin,
you passed wrong fd in connection_handler() in server.c.

Do replace sv_socket_desc with newclient.client_fsd because accept return FD which is used for communication purpose, sv_socket_desc is a socket for listen new connection.

```
while(1){
        //printf("readbef\n");
        read_size = read(newclient.client_fsd, client_message, sizeof(client_message));
        printf("read_size = %ld\n", read_size);
        printf("client_message = %s\n", client_message);
        fflush(stdout);
        read_size = write(newclient.client_fsd, client_message, sizeof(client_message));
        int n;
        sscanf(client_message, "%d", &n);
        printf("recv from %s:%hu, seq = %d\n", client_addr, client_port_num, n);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
```